# Should I use ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
My company producing hardware robotic device. **Can somebody evaluate me about ROS?** because i want to using ROS for my robot. How should i know whether i should use ROS for my company or not? What are critical evaluation of ROS that i need to take care about? The important thing is what issues i might face and what might i need to take into account?

regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200560/should-i-use-ros?/) by [ghost](https://answers.ros.org/users/21020/ghost/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-01-07

Post score: -4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This page seems to explain the benefits of using ROS fairly well: http://www.ros.org/is-ros-for-me/

As a company producing a robot, ROS has a few major benefits:

- Increased developer productivity through modular design and reusability
- It's a good way to provide a user-facing API, if you want users to write programs which run on your robot.
- Permissive licensing

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3